# Class 'WP_Widget' not found

Tags: php, widgets

I am learning Wordpress development with a tutorial where we learn to create a widget,
it is asked to create a file named `newsletterwidget.php` with the following code, but it does not say in which folder to put it:

```
class Zero_Newsletter_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('zero_newsletter', 'Newsletter', array('description' => 'Un formulaire d\'inscription à la newsletter.'));
    }
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        echo 'widget newsletter';
    }
}
```

So, as WP_Widget class is created in `wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php`, I decided to put `newsletterwidget.php` in `wp-includes` but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\newsletterwidget.php on line 5

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never work on core files which are inside wp-admin and wp-includes folder.

You'll be just working on wp-content folder.

If you're developing a plugin, you can directly put the code in your main plugin file or you can put the file inside of your plugin folder and include that file in the plugins main file.

Or if you're working with a theme, you can put the code directly in functions.php or create the php file inside your theme folder and include that file in functions.php

Comment: Ok thank you, I added `include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php';` to my `newsletterwidget.php` file, but now when I activate the plugin I get an error: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_Widget in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-widget.php on line 20`

Comment: sorry, I just replace **include** with **include_once**, no more error

Comment: Great to know that you got it solved.